# Passing ViewBag Variable to Component

Tags: octobercms

When customising the markup of a gallery component (Pollozen SimpleGallery), passing in a slug manually works fine. (The gallery component is used inside a layout).

```
[Gallery]
idGallery = 0
markup = "user"
slug = "test"
```

When trying to assign a variable that is set by a static page (Rainlab Pages) nothing happens

```
[Gallery]
idGallery = 0
markup = "user"
slug = {{page.galleryId}}
```

`{{page.galleryId}}` is displayed fine as "test" inside the actual layout. How should I assign viewBag variables to components to make this work?

Comment: can you share more details about it "assign a variable that is set by a static page" how you assign them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up having to create a partial to nest the component. Not sure why passing the variable directly does not work, but I suspect that static page variables are evaluated after the components are initialised.

```
description = "Gallery (nested for static pages compatibility)"

[viewBag]

[Gallery]
idGallery = 0
markup = "user"
slug = "{{ id }}"

==

{% for image in gallery.images %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

And inside the layout:

```
{% partial 'gallery' id=page.galleryId %}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to [pass the variable to the component](https://octobercms.com/docs/cms/components#component-variables), you have to do it in the twig section where you use the component. Here is an example:

```
[Gallery]
idGallery = 0
markup = "user"
==
{% component 'Gallery' slug=viewBag.slug %}
```

I just tested this with one of my test components and it worked as expected.